# How can I call a static Backbone.Model function from an instance of that model, without specifying the model name?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototypal-inheritance

I have static properties that I would like to access from instances of my Backbone.Model objects.  I know I could hardcode the parent constructor to call the method, but this prevents me from having polymorphic static functions.  For example, I would like to be able to override the `foo` function in `ExtendedInventory` if necessary, without having to change any other code.

```
var Inventory = Backbone.Model.extend({},
    //STATIC
    {
        foo: function() {
            alert('bar');
        }
    });

var i = new Inventory({});
i.constructor.foo(); //This works!

var ExtendedInventory = Inventory.extend({});

var ei = new ExtendedInventory({});
ei.constructor.foo(); //THIS DOES NOT WORK


//How do I generically access the `Inventory.foo()` function via the `ei` object. I would
```

Comment: So, this works but I do not understand it very well and it only works in Firefox: ei.constructor.prototype.__proto__.constructor.foo()

Comment: I wrote a blog post with examples of using static members with backbone that might be helpful to anyone coming across this question. http://taurenmills.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/backbone-js-with-class-properties/

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to class properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What doesn't work exactly, in your example? In both Firefox and IE, I get two popups with 'bar', which looks like the intended result? The static part of it appears to behave fine as well, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wevpn/).

(this is with the HEAD version of Backbone, btw; don't know if that makes a difference)

Comment: Thanks!! I was banging my head against the wall but upgrading to a newer version made it work as I had hoped.  It doesn't work with the 0.3.3 download from the main Backbone site (the error is: ei.constructor.foo is not a function).  I just wish I understood why they behave differently so I will do a diff and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm. Though the code above does work, I wouldn't leave it that way. If the function is logically accessible through an object of the class, then define an instance method in the base class that calls the class/"static" function. This makes the code cleaner and clearer, I think (plus, clients don't have to remember the somewhat arcane syntax):

```
var Inventory = Backbone.Model.extend({
    foo: function() {
        this.constructor.foo();
    }
}, {
    foo: function() {
        alert('bar');
    }
});

var i = new Inventory({});
i.foo(); //This works!

var ExtendedInventory = Inventory.extend({});

var ei = new ExtendedInventory({});
ei.foo();
```

Comment: +1 for using the second param to register static functions, even you never used it static in your example :D Inventory.foo() is working fine, thanks ;)